# How to change network name in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: networking, 17.10, desktop-environments

My setup is a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10, out of the box.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

It has set up `lo internet` and `enp1s0`.

I did what people have said which works for version 16.x but it seems not to be working for 17.10

I am wondering how I would go about changing the network name to `eth0`?

I have tried adding `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` but that did nothing:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="E0:D5:5E:02:29:84", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth0"
```

My hardware address is `E0:D5:5E:02:29:84`.

I am wondering if anyone else has this issue as I need to solve this before I can move on to the next issue of static IP address.

Comment: Why not simply move on to the issue of a static IP with enp1s0??

Comment: `eth0` was my default on one 16.04 laptop. On a new laptop with a different Ethernet adapter but also running 16.04 the system gave it a different name. Rather than changing it I simply let the system use the name it choose with no ill-effects.